# How to change page number in the ToC to sans serif?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I want my ToC to display sans serif page numbers not only for chapters, but for sections as well. I had the following code used earlier (six years ago) and it worked. Can it be recognized, why it does not work now? I assume some changes in a package. However, how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline,headings=small,BCOR=17mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % scrpage2
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\textsf{#5}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sffamily\tableofcontents\normalfont


\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter}

\addsec{A section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\addsec{Another section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\chapter{Another chapter}

\addsec{Again a section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\addsec{And another section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOMA-Script offers `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` (introduced in version 3.20) and  `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` (introduced in version 3.26) to change the font settings of entries and page numbers:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\textsf,
  pagenumberformat=\textsf
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline,headings=small,BCOR=17mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\textsf,
  pagenumberformat=\textsf
]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,figure,table}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\addsec{A section}
Some text is written here. What do you think of it?
\addsec{Another section}
Some text is written here. What do you think of it?
\chapter{Another chapter}
\addsec{Again a section}
Some text is written here. What do you think of it?
\addsec{And another section}
Some text is written here. What do you think of it?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that this does what you want as shown in my revised version of your MWE, for which thank you.

```
% tocsfprob.tex  SE 578458

\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline,headings=small,BCOR=17mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{comment}  %% added
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % scrpage2
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{comment}
\makeatletter
\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\textsf{#5}}}
\makeatother
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tocloft}  %% added plus next 2 lines
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\sffamily}


\begin{document}

\sffamily\tableofcontents\normalfont


\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter}

\addsec{A section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\addsec{Another section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\chapter{Another chapter}

\addsec{Again a section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\addsec{And another section}

Some text is written here. What do you think of it?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get a warning from the class: »Usage of package tocloft together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. ... it breaks several KOMA-Script features ... «